# Задать место для переменой

Tags: php

Подскажите как можно реализовать такое, сначала я в базу добавляю текст, я хочу указать в этом тексте места где у меня будут подставляться переменные. Например Уважаемый {name} вам пришло письмо. Извиняюсь если что то неправильно обозначил, с таким еще не сталкивался, не знаю как правильно называется.

Comment: Вы используете какой-то шаблонизатор? Или чистый PHP?

Comment: Шаблоны и шаблонизаторы это называется